# Binding Aggregation Count in Sparql

Tags: binding, count, sparql, aggregation

I have a sparql query:

```
PREFIX kpsp:<http://www.kalikautsar.com/kpsp#>  
SELECT ?name (COUNT(?yesanswer) AS ?yestotal) ?Right ?Doubt ?Wrong
 WHERE {
    ?instance rdf:type kpsp:bayi.
    ?instance kpsp:name ?name.
    ?instance kpsp:yes_answer ?yesanswer.
    BIND (?yestotal >8 AS ?Right)
    BIND (?yestotal >6 && ?yestotal <9 AS ?Doubt)
    BIND (?yestotal <7 AS ?Wrong)
}
GROUP BY ?name ?Right ?Doubt ?Wrong
```

but the result from `?Right ?Doubt ?Wrong` are not coming out, I think there is something wrong as soon as I use `?yestotal`. So how can I bind `?yestotal` (as a result of `?yesanswer count`) so that I can use it in the calculation above?

Answer (score 1):

This query is syntactically invalid.  Try at http://sparql.org/query-validator.html (after adding the missing prefix declaration)

The COUNT causes there to be a single group and aggregate over the WHERE pattern.  There are no explicit GROUP BY variables.

Use of `?name`, `?Right`, `?Doubt`, `?Wrong` in the `SELECT` is not legal because they are neither GROUP BY variables nor aggregates.

Comment: I've edit it, but it not solve my problem, how to bind the result of count aggregation?